# Anaconda CDH Parcel upgrade Python to 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, cloudera-cdh

I am currently using the Anaconda CDH parcel which is of Python 2.7.  I would like to upgrade it to Python 3.5.

I found some tutorials saying that Python version can be upgraded by using this command `conda install python=3.5`.  However, I found the below error when running this command.

```
[root@host ~]# conda install python=3.5
Fetching package metadata ...Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/...
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/...
Solving package specifications: ....

The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - enum34 -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*
  - python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I would like to ask if this is related to the network constraint of the host or the package problem.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Ruka

Answer (score 0):

Error is saying that enum34 will not work with python3.5.
Try command:

```
conda info enum34
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  May I ask if there are any ways so that I can install python 3.5 in my anaconda?  Thanks. @oshaiken

Answer (score 0):

Try this `conda create -n py35 python=3.5` for more refere below link

https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/python-35-support-anaconda